# Use CriteriaBuilder for fetching Data with Timestamp

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

i need to get the rows of a table which are newer than a spedific timestamp but with the JPA CriteriaBuilder. I am not used to JPA so maybe you guys can help me.

My source table has a column "lastModified" which contains the timestamps as a Varchar2. My approach was to use the "TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ"-Method of the Oracle DB in order to convert the Varchar2 to a Timestamp-Object so i can compare it to Timestamp-Object which i get from the Java-Program.

The following code shows an extension of the adapted criteriaBuilder but it won't work (exception).

```
cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(cb.function("TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ", Timestamp.class,  cb.literal("YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3TZR")), 
                    cb.literal(new Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").parse(filter).getTime())));
```

Comment: "It didn't work" ? How do you think that tells people what happened? Post the SQL generated (in the JPA provider log). Post the exception and its stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, that was indeed my fault. The error i get is the following:

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 161 [select generatedAlias0 from impl.UserImpl as generatedAlias0 order by TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(generatedAlias0.lastModified:param0) desc]

Maybe some error with the cb.literal("YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3TZR") part?

Comment: There is no column 161 in that JPQL string you quote. Perhaps the error has more to it ?

Comment: This is the whole error (i removed some package names before): org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 161 [select generatedAlias0 from xxx.xxxxx.xxx.xxx.configuration.masterdata.bo.impl.UserImpl as generatedAlias0 order by TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(generatedAlias0.lastModified:param0) desc]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ... (same as above)

Comment: Update: the method i posted above isn't correct. The one i am using is: cb2.function(
            "TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ", Timestamp.class, 
            ts2.get(UserImpl_.lastModified), 
            cb2.literal("YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3TZR"))

Comment: Looks to me like a Bug in your JPA provider (Hibernate?). It is missing a comma ? before the ":param0" if I read that function correctly. Hence you should raise an issue on your provider.